# Deleting a row from DataGridView and SQL Server database

Tags: c#, sql-server, datagridview

I am trying to delete a row of data in `DataGridView` and SQL Server database. On the first click on the delete button it shows

```
MessageBox.Show("Record Deleted Successfully!");
```

but the selected row was not deleted in `DataGridView` and in the database.

This is my code:

```
private void PayratesDisplay()
{
    con.Open();

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    adap = new SqlDataAdapter("select Membership AS [Membership Type], PerSession AS [Per Session], Discounted from tbl_payrates", con);

    adap.Fill(dt);

    dataGridView4.DataSource = dt;

    con.Close();
}

// Clear Data  
private void ClearData()
{
    tbMemship.Text = "";
    tbPerses.Text = "";
    tbDisc.Text = "";
    ID = 0;
}

private void btn_PRdel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (ID != 0)
    {
        con.Open();

        cmd = new SqlCommand("DELETE FROM tbl_payrates WHERE Membership = @Membership", con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Membership", ID);

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        con.Close();

        MessageBox.Show("Record Deleted Successfully!");

        PayratesDisplay();
        ClearData();
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you assigning the value for `ID`?

Comment: i declared the in the partial class Load : Form `int ID = 1;`

Comment: So you're always deleting values where `Membership = 1`? When you click the delete button, does the `ID` have the correct value?

Comment: What integer value do you get in return from *cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()*? If you are getting 0 that means there are no rows affected by your delete query.

Comment: @FelixPamittan i want to delete the selected row with `Membership=`any value do i need to change `int ID =1;` to `ID=0`?

Comment: @vnikhil I can't tell what value i am getting from `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()` because there was no error appearing when i debug

Comment: I would suggest putting this in a `try/catch` block, so you can catch any possible errors that occur.

Comment: @Josh, just assign the correct `ID`.

Comment: @FelixPamittan i changed the `ID` to `int ID=0;`. Now when i click the button nothing happens

Comment: That's obviously not going to work, because you are declaring and initializing ID to 0 that way. IF condition will always fail. Back to your other response, why do you even need an error to occur to get *cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()* return count. Care to debug and let us know the value? During debug you will also notice if at all IF condition is evaluating to true or not.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you are trying to delete the current row of the grid. Then the `ID` member is not needed and you can use something like this

```
private void btn_PRdel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var row = dataGridView4.CurrentRow;
    if (row == null) return;
    var ID = row.Cells["Membership Type"].Value;
    // The rest of the code (w/o the "if ID != 0")
}
```

Comment: `int ID = (int)row.Cells["Membership Type"].Value;` this line has an error which is `InvalidCastException`

Comment: @Josh Hmm, what it is then - string? Let me update the answer. But that's what you are trying to do, right?

Comment: I am deleting a row with integers in it

Comment: @Josh Hmm, that couldn't be true - both `select` and `delete` sql statements operate on `tbl_payrates` and the delete is filtering by `Membership` column, which also is included in the grid (just with alias), so its either an `int` and the original cast should succeed or not an `int`.

Comment: the column `Discounted` is in varchar(50)

Answer (score 0):

Change your code like this

```
int r=cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();
if(r>0){MessageBox.Show("Record Deleted Successfully!");}
```